# MPEG-TS playback with MPlayer: current timestamp and duration are wrong

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mplayer

Recently I have been playing a lot of MPEG-TS videos on MPlayer. The sources of the videos are unclear to me, so I have no idea of with which software these TS videos were created.

The problem is that **MPlayer's OSD often reports the wrong timestamp and duration; this seems to be MPEG-TS specific** since I have never encountered (or at least I cannot recall encountering) such problems with MPEG-4 or H.264.

For instance, I have cut (with FFmpeg) the following sample from one of my TS videos: [sample.ts hosted on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5kfE3SYan7oN0V4N1RFSU1kdjg/edit?usp=sharing) (no copyright infridgement intended). `ffprobe sample.ts` prints

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'sample.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:09.99, start: 1.423344, bitrate: 2827 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], max. 104857 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 123 kb/s
```

When I play this video with MPlayer (no options passed), the osd timestamp begins at around `00:00:01`, while the duration reported is `00:03:40` (note that this video is only 10 seconds long!).

I have also tested this on `ffplay` (with `-vf showinfo`), and the timestamp issue is consistent with MPlayer: the info shown for the first frame is

```
[Parsed_showinfo_0 @ 0x7fbd5242c620] n:0 pts:129003 pts_time:1.43337 pos:564 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 s:1920x1080 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:405DDE4C plane_checksum:[58C83B11 F8FAD95C B874C9D0]
```

Note that the `pts_time` is `1.43337` instead of the expected `0`. So **I guess the problem is related to libav***. Anyway, **at least `ffplay` reports the correct duration, while MPlayer gets it wrong**, which makes the scene more puzzling for me.

So my questions are

1. **Is this a known issue/bug?**
2. **Is there any option to fix this?**

This is really annoying for me since I need to extract frame timestamps for FFmpeg seeking from time to time. Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

For your reference, my MPlayer is `MPlayer UNKNOWN-4.2.1` installed on OS X 10.9.3 from the `mplayer-devel @36449_4+osd` port of MacPorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly I asked this question due to lack of knowledge of MPEG-TS. The behavior is expected, since MPEG-TS was simply designed this way. According to Etienne Buira on [MPlayer-users mailing list](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.video.mplayer.user/65828),

> AFAIK the format does not allow to reliably know where it is in the
>   stream (designed to be continuous, and as the timestamps cannot grow
>   forever, there is a need to cycle them).

Recreate the timestamps with FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -c:a copy -c:v copy -fflags +genpts output.ts
```